# Why does my image suddenly shrink when adding into flex-container? Why doesn't the flex container adjust?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, viewport

I just started learning html/css and am currently working on my first Website. This may be a dumb question, but why the does my "navbar-left_img" image shrink when I add it into the flex container of it's parent, "Navbar". I understand that it's size of 12.3% has gone from being related to the size of the entire viewport to the size of the container, but I made the width of the container 100% (so the size of the entire viewport). So surely it shouldn't make a difference, right?

This is the image size I want.

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Noto Sans";
}

.navbar-left_img {
  width: 12.3%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 3%;
}
```

But when I do this, the image suddenly shrinks.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Noto Sans";
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-left_img {
  width: 12.3%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto Sans" />

  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-left">
        <a href="https://www.instantadvantages.com/"><img src="images/Instant%20Advantages%20logo%20black.png" alt="Logo" class="navbar-left_img" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-right"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: we need to see the html code

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry, just added it

Comment: I made a snippet of the code you posted however I did NOT fix the malformed HTML - please note that the body does not go inside the head element for example.

Comment: With your first set of CSS rules the navbar-left takes up 100% of the window width, but with the second set it only takes 50% of the width. 12.3% of 100% is more than 12.3% of 50%. The way to check this yourself is by using [the browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools). Specifically the "inspector" tool.

Answer (score -1):

When you set the width of an element in CSS as a percentage (e.g., width: 12.3%;), it is calculated relative to the width of its containing element, not the viewport. In your case, when you set the width of your "navbar-left_img" image as a percentage inside a flex container ("Navbar"), it's calculated based on the width of the "Navbar" container.

If the "Navbar" container has a width of 100% of the viewport, that means your image's width is 12.3% of the "Navbar" container's width, not 12.3% of the viewport.

To make your image size relative to the viewport, you can set the width of the "Navbar" container itself to 100% of the viewport. However, you also need to ensure that the parent elements of "Navbar" are also set to 100% width all the way up to the html and body elements. This ensures that your entire layout adjusts to the viewport size.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).